# How to implement slug in url for a existing route in Razor pages?

Tags: c#, seo, url-routing, razor-pages, .net-5

I have an e-commerce website already built. In that, the product page route looks like

```
https://localhost:5000/product/{productId}
```

I have implemented it in razor pages by using the `@page` directive as

```
@page https://localhost:5000/product/{productId}
```

Now I have spoken to an SEO developer they wanted URL's with `SLUG` for SEO purposes as shown below

```
@page https://localhost:5000/product/{SLUG?}/{productId}
```

To achieve this URL, I have used `?` to make an attribute in URL optional and changed the route basically. But the problem is that I have used `<a href="/product/{productId}" in many
other places, so I can't change the URL directly with a slug.

so I have decided that all the `<a>` that uses the previous URL as `https://localhost:5000/product/{productId}` should be permanent redirected to `https://localhost:5000/product/{SLUG?}/{productId}`

How can I redirect from one URL to another without adding a separate page and pagemodel to take  hit on the route and then redirect?